Why is the wireshark checksum different from the accepted one?
There is the following code:
(its functionality is parsing ethernet frames)
uint8_t raw_eth_frame_input(const pbuf_t *eth_frame)
{
  
  eth_len_rx = eth_frame->tot_len; /// - присваиваем переменной eth_len_rx значение длины длины кадра, которое взято из структуры eth_frame параметра tot_len;
  pbuf_copy_partial(eth_frame, eth_data_rx, eth_len_rx, 0); /// - копируем принятый кадр eth_frame в массив eth_data_rx длинной eth_len_rx;
  eth_header = (eth_hdr_t*)eth_data_rx;/// - выбираем эзернет заголок 14 байт (по 6 байт мак и 2 байта тип);
  const uint8_t   *eth_payload = (const uint8_t*)((u8_t *)eth_data_rx + SIZEOF_ETH_HDR);
  
  eth_header->type = ntohs(eth_header->type);
  switch (eth_header->type) /// - проверяем что за тип пакета арп или айпи;
  {
    /// - проверяем что лежит в IP заголовке;
    case (ETHTYPE_IP):
    {
      ip_header      = (ip_hdr_t*)  ((u8_t *)eth_payload);
      const uint8_t  *ip_payload      = (const uint8_t*)((u8_t *)eth_payload+IP_HLEN);
      ip_addr_t dest_ip = 
      {
        .addr = ip_header->dest.addr
      };
      //Запоминаем IP источника
     
      //Все ICMP пакеты пропускаем в lwip
      if(IPH_PROTO(ip_header) == IP_PROTO_ICMP)
      {
        if(is_my_ip(dest_ip))//отправляем в лвайпи
        {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      ip_header->_len = ntohs(ip_header->_len);
      ip_header->_id = ntohs(ip_header->_id);
      ip_header->src.addr = ntohl(ip_header->src.addr);
      ip_header->dest.addr = ntohl(ip_header->dest.addr);
      ip_header->_chksum = ntohl(ip_header->_chksum);
      
      if(IPH_PROTO(ip_header) == IP_PROTO_UDP) //если тип юдп
      {
        udp_header   = (udp_hdr_t*)((u8_t *)ip_payload);
        const uint8_t   *udp_data_ptr = (const uint8_t*)((u8_t *)ip_payload+UDP_HLEN);
        udp_header->src = ntohs(udp_header->src);
        udp_header->dest = ntohs(udp_header->dest); 
        udp_header->len = ntohs(udp_header->len); //размер полезной информации без всех служ. заголовков
        udp_header->chksum = ntohs(udp_header->chksum);
        }
      
      if(IPH_PROTO(ip_header) == IP_PROTO_TCP)
      {
        if(is_my_ip(dest_ip))
        {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    } break;
    case (ETHTYPE_ARP):
    {
      return 1; //отправляем в lwip все ARP запросы
    } break;
  }
  return 0;
}

In debugging mode, I monitor 3 structures: eth_header, ip_header, udp_header. In the latter, checksum is incorrectly displayed (it differs from the one in the packet intercepted by wireshark).
I am sending packages via packet sender.
Sender: PC
Recipient: STM32H743ZI microcontroller
p.s.I am attaching a photo with an example.
enter image description here
I started reading about udp packets and realized that maybe wireshark intercepts the packet before calculating the checksum on the network card -> it intercepts the data and looks at the checksum that is embedded in the packet (not counted). If you have any ideas on how to make sure that the checksum field has the correct value, write

As mentioned in the comment in your picture, this could be caused by UDP checksum offload. With that, the OS does not compute the checksum for transmitted packets, and the Ethernet controller calculates it when the packet gets physically transmitted on the wire. You could turn that feature off and see if it changes.
